# What is a forwarding pointer?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

I recently came across the concept of "forwarding pointer" and have not been able to find sources of a precise definition. In my case this was mentioned and briefly (but poorly) explained during a discussion on distributed systems.

Could you elaborate on the concept, its usual context(s) and possible other names by which this is also known as?

Comment: In what context did you see it? Where did you try to find the answer for yourself?

Comment: I still fail to see what is unclear about this question: 1- I was able to given easily a precise technical answer. 2- if this answer is incomplete, which does not seem to be the case, it would be interesting to see it completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Forwarding pointer" is the name of a technique used in [garbage
collection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) when data cells are being moved to a different
storage location, either because you are using a [copying collection
technique](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2003fa/lectures/sec24.htm) such as [Cheney's collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm), or because you are doing a [compaction phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark-compact_algorithm) to reduce
memory fragmentation. Compaction is usually associated with mark-and-sweep collectors, but it could be used in other contexts, though the care required by forwarding pointers may entail overhead that is more naturally acceptable with mark-and-sweep.

The forwarding pointer replaces the data cell that has been moved, so that any piece of code trying to access that cell through its old address can find the forwarding pointer to the new address. Exactly like a person moving to a new house will leave her new address on the mailbox (or at the post-office) of her old house. Of course, the code and data must be organized so that forwarding pointers may be recognized as such.

As far as I know, this was historically the first widespread use of the concept of forwarding pointer. But the idea of using forwarding pointers can be considered, and has been considered in other situations that require moving data to a different location, for example:

- The concept is used in [mobile computing](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_95/journal/vol1/mkh/article1.html) when an agent moves to a
  different location (agency) and must still receive messages sent to
  its former location.
- The concept is also used in [data-base implementation](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2013/forwarding-pointers-in-heaps/) when the organization and management
  of data requires moving some part of it to another location.

Basically, ***forwarding pointers* are a way of reorganizing incrementally
the storage structures or system organizations without disrupting (too much) on going computations,
and avoiding a complete sweep of the system space, by leaving the new address of moved constituents at their former location.**

*(You could have found some of that yourself by searching the web and wikipedia).*